# Is it possible to have multiple automated builds within a single team project collection?

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a team project collection. This team project collection contains many Visual Studio solutions. The main solution is our product. It is built on our build machine.

I have created a new test project solution for automated UI tests. I want to automate the build process for this new solution, so I have created a new build definition to build the project. I have created it within the same team project collection as our main product solution.

I want this new test project to build onto the same build machine (thus using the same build controller) as the main product build.

How do I do this?

Is it possible to create a new build agent and specify that my build definition uses this new build agent (which has its own working directory)?

Or is it a requirement that a different build process should be in a different team project collection?

What is the best way for me to go about this? Any ideas or thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is possible (I managed to work it out), and yes I did need to create a new build agent.

When setting up a build process template, in the 'Advanced' settings, under 'Agent Settings', I can specify which build agent to use (in the 'Name Filter' field).

Just remember that existing build definitions might be set to run on ALL build agents - because by default the name filter is '*' - so it will run on all available build agents. Make sure to change the name filter so that your other build definitions will build using the correct build agent.